# use expect in ansible execute a install a command and responds to prompts

Tags: elasticsearch, ansible

I'm creating a playbook for the installation of elasticsearch plugins. There is you have to accept the installation.

My code:

```
- name: Configure Elasticsearch
  hosts: elasticsearch
  gather_facts: true
  become: true
  tasks:

    - name: Install Elasticsearch Plugins for AWS
      expect:
        command: "/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-plugin install discovery-ec2"
        responses:
          Question:
            - Continue with installation? [y/N]: Y
        echo: yes
        timeout: 30
```

I receive the following error:

```
> @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\n@    
> WARNING: plugin requires additional permissions    
> @\r\n@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\n*
> java.lang.RuntimePermission accessDeclaredMembers\r\n*
> java.lang.RuntimePermission getClassLoader\r\n*
> java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks\r\n*
> java.net.SocketPermission * connect,resolve\r\nSee
> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html\r\nfor
> descriptions of what these permissions allow and the associated
> risks.\r\n\r\nContinue with installation? [y/N]", "stdout_lines": ["->
> Installing discovery-ec2", "-> Downloading discovery-ec2 from
> elastic", "", "[                                                
> "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@", "@    
> WARNING: plugin requires additional permissions     @",
> "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@", "*
> java.lang.RuntimePermission accessDeclaredMembers", "*
> java.lang.RuntimePermission getClassLoader", "*
> java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks", "*
> java.net.SocketPermission * connect,resolve", "See
> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html",
> "for descriptions of what these permissions allow and the associated
> risks.", "", "Continue with installation? [y/N]"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
    - name: Install Elasticsearch Plugins for AWS
  expect:
    command: "/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-plugin install discovery-ec2 -s"
    responses:
      (.*)Continue with installation : "y"
    timeout: 10
```